# Dimension of an array changed inside the function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I wrote a function to handle arrays.

I passed the 2D array into the function as "someFunc(*dna)" but inside the function, it turned out to be 3D.

Why has the dimension changed? How can I keep the same dimension of the argument I passed inside the function?

```
import numpy as np
import random

q=np.random.random((5,4))

def someFunc(*dna):
    return ((np.shape(dna)))

print (q)
print (np.shape(q))
print(someFunc(q))
```

## Returns

```
[[ 0.87994033  0.85120494  0.75284745  0.48595008]
 [ 0.71889884  0.95544306  0.70028042  0.30932712]
 [ 0.04329341  0.46292282  0.35225021  0.08891277]
 [ 0.9704255   0.92635685  0.56120996  0.19240052]
 [ 0.27435325  0.71029224  0.55805384  0.26967641]]
(5, 4)
(1, 5, 4)
```

Comment: Why `*dna` instead of plain `dna`?

Comment: BTW, that `import random` is pointless - you aren't using the standard `random` module, you are using Numpy's own `random` function.

Comment: Why do even want a function for this? You can simply access the array's `.shape` attribute: `q.shape`

Comment: @hpaulj  Because my actual code is really big and i don't want to dump all my code here which is meaning less. I want to unpack all elements inside the array (dna) instead of just playing around with its index or its shape, i referred [here] (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists). To have ease of access to the elements (in dna) i want to keep the same dimension of variable "q"

Comment: `*dna` unpacks a tuple or list, not an array.  Look at `dna` inside the funcition - it's a 1 element tuple.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you , i got it now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues - what `*args` does, and what's the shape of a tuple.

The proper use of *arg is to receive elements of a tuple:

```
def foo(*dna):
    a,b,c = dna
    print(dna, a)
```

Giving 3 arguments works, giving 1, even a tuple does not:

```
In [235]: foo(1,2,3)
(1, 2, 3) 1
In [236]: foo((1,2,3))
...
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

Adding a * in the input unpacks them:

```
In [237]: foo(*(1,2,3))
(1, 2, 3) 1
```

Same goes for an array:

```
In [238]: foo(np.arange(3))
...
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
In [239]: foo(*np.arange(3))
(0, 1, 2) 0
```

`args` is a tuple, regardless of what is provided:

```
def bar(*args):
    return args

In [241]: bar(1,2,3)
Out[241]: (1, 2, 3)
In [242]: bar((1,2,3))
Out[242]: ((1, 2, 3),)    # note the extra tuple wrapping
In [243]: bar(*(1,2,3))   # unpack as in 241
Out[243]: (1, 2, 3)
In [244]: bar(np.arange(3))
Out[244]: (array([0, 1, 2]),)    # again, the tuple wrapping
In [245]: bar(*np.arange(3))
Out[245]: (0, 1, 2)
```

Taking the shape of a tuple amounts to taking the shape of the array formed from the tuple

```
In [247]: np.shape((np.arange(3),))
Out[247]: (1, 3)
In [249]: np.array((np.arange(3),))
Out[249]: array([[0, 1, 2]])
```

Comment: That's perfect. It is really hard to shift from MATLAB to Python without clear idea about python's control flow. Thanks again! 
Thanks you all!

Answer (score 2):

Because `*dna` collects passed arguments into [tuple](https://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists). So what you have done equals

```
def someFunc(dna):
    return np.shape([dna]) # Notice extra brackets
```

To keep the same dimension, just remove * before `dna`.

Comment: You're burning through this year's parenthesis quota real fast :P

Comment: @AndrasDeak Recycled them. :)